# Find the maximum and minimum value of $ \sin ^4 \theta + \cos ^4 \theta $?

Tags: trigonometry

Please suggest suitable approach for this problem

Comment: In which interval? It's periodic with period $\frac{\pi}{2}$, so it will have a lot of maxima and minima. But if you're restricting to $\left[0,\frac{\pi}{2}\right]$, then it has one minimum and two maxima at the ends.

Comment: I solved it the answer is 1 and 1/2.

Comment: Setting $x=\sin^2\theta$ this reduces to finding the extrema of $x^2+(1-x)^2$ for $x\in[0,1]$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Note that
$$1 = (\sin^2\theta + \cos^2\theta)^2$$
and use $\sin2\theta = 2\sin\theta\cos\theta.$

Comment: Yes that's the observation ;)